# How to remove NaN on CSV?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, export-to-csv

I have a .csv file of a table consisting of 12 col and 30k rows. One of the col is 'mentions', some of the data are empty (NaN). I am trying to remove all the rows where mentions = NaN. I don't want to fill it with new data. I just wanna remove those rows so they wont be part of the analysis.

Please help. Thank you.

I will be saving the csv file after as another file to conduct a network analysis via networkx

Comment: I hope my code help you, I posted it [in stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64960024/13065379)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `DataFrame` is named `df`:

```py
df = df.dropna(subset=["mentions"])
```